# Distributed meeting scheduler through calendar sync

Tags: outlook, synchronization, google-calendar-api

We can start syncing events between Google Calendar and Microsoft
Outlook,but what about syncing multiple Google calendars and searching
for possible common meeting dates and timings for geographically
distributed individuals ( and then possibly importing  the searched
schedules and events into Microsoft Outlook and maintain an accurate
model of the users' schedule/availability ) ? Is this feature
available in Google calendar ?
Can someone direct me to programming tools so that I can develop it if
its not available ? 
Ideas for any other platform?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do. The place to start is  http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html
As far as approaches you can could build a vsto plugin that pulls the data from the google sources and inserts them in to the outlook calendar via [OOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208225.aspx) or you could build a stand alone app that calls google and the inserts them in to exchange calendar directly via EWS/webdav or using CDO/[RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) etc.

Whats version of outlook exchange are you running ? How do you want the app to run .. automatically? realtime etc? answer these and I could sugest an approach.

Comment: I would want to run it realtime ,because people change their schedule realtime.I would want to build a standalone app.
Using it with Outlook 2007 is not as important as getting it functionally done first. For simplicity let assume all users have  gmail .

Comment: Ok real time you will probally have to have windows service or standalone that uses the Google Calendar API to get your common meeting dates from your multiple calandars then use WEBDav/EWS to insert the dates into the exchange calandar(s) that you want. The hardest part really would be learning the google api to search for common dates ..